# DocumentDB SQL ARRAY_CONTAINS

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

In this case, the documents look like:

```
{
 "id" : "1",
 "Properties" : [
  {
   "Name" : "Leonard",
   "Result" : "Pass",
   "Grade" : "A"
  },
  {
   "Name" : "Sheldon",
   "Result" : "Pass",
   "Grade" : "A"
  },
  {
   "Name" : "Raj",
   "Result" : "Fail",
   "Grade" : "F"
  },
  {
   "Name" : "Howard",
   "Result" : "Pass",
   "Grade" : "B"
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to write a query which returns the elements with the `"Result" : "Pass"`. I have tried `ARRAY_CONTAINS()` with query

```
SELECT * FROM d as c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.Result, {"Result" : "Pass"}, true)
```

The Problem with the query is that it returns the whole of the array in as it is able to find `"Result": "Pass"` in the array. How should I modify or change the query such that the result contains only those elements of the array which has `"Result": "Pass"`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to select the `Properties`

```
SELECT  c.Properties[0] as Result
FROM c
JOIN tag IN c.Properties
WHERE tag.Result = "Pass"
```

Comment: Apparently, the query you suggested is also returning the whole array if one of the items of the array has `"Result" : "Pass"`. I need only those items from the array which has `"Result" : "Pass"`.

Comment: Not really, it returns only those object which has result pass.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query which will return the id and only the matching items from the Properties array.

`SELECT d.id, property
FROM d JOIN property IN d.properties
WHERE property.Result= "Pass"`